# How to list all databases in Azure CLI

Tags: mysql, database, azure, command-line-interface, azure-sql-database

I am new to Azure CLI. I was trying out some commands to get a list of all database present in the Azure account from CLI.

I have used this command to get the information

```
az mysql db list --resource-group --server-name
```

But I want to find the list of all databases without giving any details(For eg. Resource group name and server name.)

I am trying to write a shell scripting but nothing is working.

Answer (score 3):

```
az mysql server list
```

or you can run az resource list and then filter the output for example

```
az resource list -o table --query "[?type=='Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers'].[name,resourceGroup]"
```

or for a more elegant output:

```
az resource list -o table --query "[?type=='Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers'].{name:name, group:resourceGroup}"
```

If you are using powershell

```
az resource list -o table | select-string 'Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers'
```

Or grep for Linux/mac

```
az resource list -o table | grep 'Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers'
```

for-o (--output) you can use 'table', 'tsv' or 'jsonc'

Comment: Here's some reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest
http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** You can configure the default group, but server name required to provide every time.

**az mysql db list**

**Arguments:**

```
--server-name -s [Required]: The name of the server

--resource-group -g        : Name of resource group
```

You can configure the default group using **az configure --defaults group=name**

For more details, refer "[az mysql db](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/mysql/db?view=azure-cli-latest#az_mysql_db_list)".

Answer (score 1):

This one gives you all Single Instance servers and Flexible servers at once using az graph query:

```
az graph query -q "Resources | where type has 'Microsoft.DBforMySQL' | project id, type, subscriptionId"
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract all databases in all MSSQL servers in the subscription I use this command:

```
az sql db list --ids $(az sql server list --query [].id -o tsv)
```

could you try something like this for mysql.